# Replace xsi:nil=“true” with open and close tags

Tags: xslt

I need to do the following transformation in order to get a message pass through a integration broker which does not understand `xsi:nil=“true”`. I know that for strings having some thing like `<abc></abc>` is not same as `<abc xsi:nil=“true”/>` but I have no option.

My input XML:

```
<PART>
<LENGTH_UOM xsi:nil="1"/>
            <WIDTH xsi:nil="1"/>
</PART>
```

Expected outcome:

```
<PART>
    <LENGTH_UOM><LENGTH_UOM>
    <WIDTH></WIDTH>
</PART>
```

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of all the attributes for all the elements?

Answer (score 1):

To remove all `xsi:nil` attributes combine the *identity template* with an empty template matching `xsi:nil`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://xsi.com">     
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">                 <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@xsi:nil" />                <!-- empty template -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you only want to remove those whose value is `true` use the following empty template instead.

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='1' or .='true']" />
```

Concerning the opening and closing tag topic [I suggest reading this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7583923/1305969) in which *Martin Honnen* states that (in the comments of the answer):

> I am afraid whether an empty element is marked up as  or  or  is not something that matters with XML and is usually not something you can control with XSLT processors.