# Why is my XSL outputting siblings as children of an empty element?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
    <text>
        <h6>Title</h6>
        <p>Text is right here</p>
        <h6>Title</h6>
        <p>Text is right here</p>
        <pagebreak orientation="portrait@1col" />
        <h2>This is an H2 Title</h2>
        <figure-gallery>
            <figure>
                <figure-headline>Headline</figure-headline>
                <figure-asset>Image tag to display image</figure-asset>
                <figure-caption>Caption of the image</figure-caption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <figure-headline>Headline</figure-headline>
                <figure-asset>Image tag to display image</figure-asset>
                <figure-caption>Caption of the image</figure-caption>
            </figure>
        </figure-gallery>
        <h1>This is an H1 title</h1>
    </text>
```

And the following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pagebreak[1]">
    <div id="empty-html-container" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="h6">
    <div class="Title">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <div class="Text">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure-asset">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure">
    <div>
        <header>
            <xsl:copy-of select="figure-headline/p/node()"/>
        </header>
        <section>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="figure-asset"/>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <xsl:value-of select="figure-caption"/>
        </footer>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure-gallery">
    <div class="figure-gallery">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Why is the output coming out like this (sibling elements after the pagebreak are children of the pagebreak template output)...

```
<section>
    <div class="Title">Title</div>
    <div class="BulletText">Text is right here</div>
    <div class="BulletTitle">Title</div>
    <div class="BulletText">Text is right here</div>
    <div class="BulletTitle">Title</div>
    <div class="BulletText">Text is right here</div>
    <div id="empty-html-container">
        <h2>This is an H2 Title</h2>
        <div class="figure-gallery">
            <div>
                <header>Headline</header>
                <section>Image tag to display image</section>
                <footer>Caption of the image</footer>
            </div>
            <div>
                <header>Headline</header>
                <section>Image tag to display image</section>
                <footer>Caption of the image</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>This is an H1 title</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

...instead of coming out like this (sibling elements after the pagebreak remain sibiling elements after the pagebreak):

```
<section>
    <div class="Title">Title</div>
    <div class="BulletText">Text is right here</div>
    <div class="BulletTitle">Title</div>
    <div class="BulletText">Text is right here</div>
    <div class="BulletTitle">Title</div>
    <div class="BulletText">Text is right here</div>
    <div id="empty-html-container"></div>
    <h2>This is an H2 Title</h2>
    <div class="figure-gallery">
        <div>
            <header>Headline</header>
            <section>Image tag to display image</section>
            <footer>Caption of the image</footer>
        </div>
        <div>
            <header>Headline</header>
            <section>Image tag to display image</section>
            <footer>Caption of the image</footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>This is an H1 title</h1>
</section>
```

The empty element is to allow JavaScript do some work after the browser loads the page.

One curious thing, when I put text inside the "div" in the output, then it will work as expected, but if I leave it empty, then the siblings become children.

Right now, I have a "br" tag because it doesn't show up and it solves my problem, but it adds a line return I do not want because it messes with my design.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In what context do you see that effect, does that happen in the direct output of your XSLT processor or only when a browser's HTML parser parses the transformation result (and misinterprets the empty element markup perhaps because you have not used `xsl:output method="html"`)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the result you show at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BY so I guess somehow you only see it inside the browser when you feed HTML serialized as XML where then the XML empty element syntax might lead the browser's HTML parser to construct a different tree than you expect. So make sure you use `xsl:output method="html"`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the result you show. I tested the given code with `xsltproc`(Linux) and the result is similar to your expected sample XML. Adding `xsl:output method="html"` does not change anything.

Comment: TBH I'm new to XSLT and XML to HTML conversions. Further that with working inside a CRM system, using Apache Freemarker which I'm not familiar with, custom built by a third party European vendor for my employer (can anyone say language barrier), and it's a perfect storm for screwing up...lol.  I'll check the output and see if that helps first.

Comment: Well that output to HTML did the trick. It must've been the way Chrome was parsing the code and displaying it. I knew it was something I needed to know. Back to the books for more reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 
    `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>`
after the stylesheet declaration.

Produces :
    `<div id="empty-html-container"></div>`

Found in : [XML empty tag being converted to open and closing tag pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583923/xml-empty-tag-being-converted-to-open-and-closing-tag-pair)